# Windows : Delete directories

Tags: java, windows

```
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Could not move: C:\gram\zmedia.
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.filesystem.Policy.error(Policy.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.core.filesystem.provider.FileStore.move(FileStore.java:415)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.filesystem.local.LocalFile.move(LocalFile.java:352)
    at com.zmedia.zide.config.model.Service.updateDeploymentSetup(Service.java:923)
    at com.zmedia.zide.config.model.Service.update(Service.java:886)
    at com.zmedia.zide.util.ServiceAPI.create(ServiceAPI.java:239)
    at com.zmedia.zide.ui.wizards.pages.CreateServicePage$5.run(CreateServicePage.java:525)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
Caused by: org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Problems encountered while deleting files.
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.filesystem.local.LocalFile.delete(LocalFile.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.core.filesystem.provider.FileStore.move(FileStore.java:411)
    ... 6 more
```

Hi All ,

We developed a plugin on top of eclipse . We gave a option for users to remove their old projects in eclipse .

**Issue :**
If a file is opened on this directory or any process using their directory on delete operation will be the problem . This issue is specific for only windows users .

Is there any way to force delete a directory on windows?

How can I notify to users  like  this "**This process is using our directory . Please close this process and proceed**" .

Is there any way to know which process is accessing this?

Comment: [Apache Commons `FileUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) has a method called `forceDelete(File file)`. I've not tried it personally but you might want to give it a try!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker), it has a portable version and commandline options (depending on its license) you may be able to ship it with your plugin and use it via commandline to unlock the used files.

Comment: I remember having lot's of fun with ant / eclipse and locked files under windows.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to force delete a directory on windows?

You can kill the process holding the lock or ask the user to close the process.  Unfortunately this could be the eclipse process itself or explorer.

Answer (score 0):

In a debug situation, to know which process is using a file, you could use the excellent Process Explorer [as decribed here](http://windowsxp.mvps.org/processlock.htm).

AFAIK, there is no simple way with the Java SDK to know which process is using it.

What you could do is mark the file as deleteOnExit() and it would be removed when the user actually quits Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Probably its your own plugin that's locking the files. Try to implement a method/strategy to "release" them before attempting to delete. You can use Apache Commons IO to help you build/identifying this. Take a look at the [FileDeleteStrategy](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileDeleteStrategy.html). Also check the "FORCE" option.

Comment: I tried this . It's not working . I saw FileDeleStrategy source code there is nothing special handling It just calls File.delete .

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that there is good way in Java alone to find out what process is keeping you from deleting the folder. Also that may be a little aggressive. Why not copy if you cannot move and present a dialog that lists the projects that could not be moved (or deleted) so that the user can take care of it by himself. There could be a reason a file was kept open after all.

Comment: How can i get which process is holding the file or folder in java?

Comment: I do not know, if that is possible at all. That's why I suggested to try to delete (or move - if that is what you do) and only if that fails fall back to copy and simply tell the user that the delete failed.